# PHP/GD - photo thumbnails in a gallery: random display

Tags: php, image, gd

I have only basic skills in php, and I had to put photo galleries on a website. As this website will be used by people that know little in programming, I wanted a simple use: upload a folder with photos (edit: through FTP), the photo gallery thumbnails are automatically displayed, and a click on the thumbnail will display the full size image.

I used a script that generates a thumbnail on the fly. This script just seems to work fine if I call it directly in the browser. I obtain my thumbnail. But when I display a gallery in my page, each image source being a call to my script, only a random subset of the thumbnails are displayed, the others only display the alt text. For example, on a gallery of 8, the first time I display the page I may get only 3,4 and 7, and after refreshing 1,3,5,6,8:

I could find no error message given by the other thumbs not loading, but here my basic skills in php may fail me, perhaps I just did not kow where to find such an error message.

Here is the call to my script:

```
<a href="resources/galleries/example.jpg"><img src="mini.php?f=example.jpg" alt="Photo" /></a>
```

and mini.php used GD:

```
<?php
$ratio = 150;  
$dir = './resources/galleries';  

if (!isset($_GET['f'])) { 
    header('location: index.php'); 
    exit();  
}  
else { 
    $image = $_GET['f'];
    $tableau = @getimagesize($dir.'/'.$image); 
    if ($tableau == FALSE) { 
        header('location: index.php'); 
        exit(); 
    } 
    else { 
        // if jpeg
        if ($tableau[2] == 2) { 
          $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir.'/'.$image); 
          if ($tableau[0] > $tableau[1]) { 
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor(round(($ratio/$tableau[1])*$tableau[0]), $ratio); 
            imagecopyresampled($im, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, round(($ratio/$tableau[1])*$tableau[0]), $ratio, $tableau[0], $tableau[1]); 
          } 
          else { 
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor($ratio, round(($ratio/$tableau[0])*$tableau[1])); 
            imagecopyresampled($im, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ratio, round($tableau[1]*($ratio/$tableau[0])), $tableau[0], $tableau[1]); 
          }
          header ("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
          imagejpeg ($im); 
        }
        elseif ($tableau[2] == 3) { // PNG
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($dir.'/'.$image); 
            if ($tableau[0] > $tableau[1]) { 
              $im = imagecreatetruecolor(round(($ratio/$tableau[1])*$tableau[0]), $ratio);
              imagecopyresampled($im, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, round(($ratio/$tableau[1])*$tableau[0]), $ratio, $tableau[0], $tableau[1]); 
            } 
            else { 
              $im = imagecreatetruecolor($ratio, round(($ratio/$tableau[0])*$tableau[1])); 
              imagecopyresampled($im, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ratio, round($tableau[1]*($ratio/$tableau[0])), $tableau[0], $tableau[1]); 
            } 
            header ("Content-type: image/png"); 
            imagepng ($im); 
        }
    }
}  
?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You say that users upload a FOLDER on your website ? Could it be that the photo names have special characters or spaces that you don't check on upload ?

Comment: In fact it is just ftp upload outside the website, so, no, file names are not checked. But here, I double-checked the names and there is no problem. Anyway, as I said, each thumbnail will display sometimes, and all work when the thumbnailer is called directly in the browser.

Comment: Ok. Could it be a path error ? Is mini.php in a subfolder . Because if it's the case and that you call it from the image, then maybe your '$dir.'/'' is not proper anymore... If not, i'm sorry I haven't found any solution...